# My ubuntu became really laggy suddenly

Tags: 20.04

My ubuntu has became laggy and especially qtcreator is extremely slow and sometimes everything is really slow sometimes i have to wait like 5 minutes after clicking on qtcreator or even after clicking on shutdown.

specs:
1.6 GhzGHz Intel Core i5-8265U 8th Gen processor
8GB DDR4 RAM
Intel UHD 620 Graphics

it is on dual boot with windows on a 256gb ssd
and for storage reasons i have a partition on my  hdd for home directory.

[image: Top output]

dmesg:
https://pastebin.com/rzUfTNue

Comment: what are the system specs?

Comment: Have you used `top` to check your resources?

Comment: I have added specs and "top" output . It happened suddenly it was working fine 3- 4 days before but then all of a sudden it started lagging. And i am not sure if it is related to this issue but as ubuntu was really laggy I switched to windows yesterday and noticed its C: drive (ubuntu and windows are on same ssd in two partition)  wasbehaving weird. it filled all space by itself then i deleted some files now it is filling up some space sometimes and sometimes it freeing up space by itself.

Comment: It would be real cool if you could just add it to your answer. Click the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1288630/edit) Button below your answer and copy the contents instead of making screenshots....

Comment: Add your `dmesg` output (copy and paste it , not using sceenshots), try to get the relevant parts -it is not your CPU that slows you down

Comment: dmesg output is very big and copy pasting will make it difficult to read